# Dependency injection in a scheduled JobService with Dagger 2

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger, jobservice

What's the best way to inject dependencies in a scheduled jobservice in Android.
My JobService is scheduled to run in the night to do some stuff.

In JobService constructor i'm trying to inject my dependencies over my Application class.

```
MyApp.component().inject(this);
```

But sometimes `MyApp` isn't initialized at this time and so the injection failes.

Maybe i'm using Dagger in a wrong way? Or do i have to create an own component for the JobService?

Here is my Application class

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
  private static AppComponent appComponent;

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    buildAppComponent();

  }

  public static AppComponent component(){
    return appComponent;
  }

  private void buildAppComponent(){
    if(appComponent == null){
        appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder()
            .appModule(new AppModule(this))
            .build();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use AndroidInjector to inject android classes such as Activities/Fragments/Services/BroadcastReceivers/ContentProviders.

First make sure you added dagger-android dependency from your `build.gradle`

```
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.16'
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.16'
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.16'
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.16'
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.16'
```

Then make sure you app component inherit from `AndroidInjector`

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {AndroidSupportInjectionModule.class,
                      ApplicationModule.class,
                      ActivityBuilderModule::class,
                      ServiceBuilderModule::class})
public interface ApplicationComponent extends AndroidInjector<MyApp> {
    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        Builder application(MyApp application);

        ApplicationComponent build();
    }
}
```

`ActivityBuilderModule` and `ServiceBuilderModule` reference all you activitiy and service subcomponents using an handy annotation `ContributesAndroidInjector` that will generate the subcomponent automatically for you

```
@Module
abstract class ActivityBuilderModule {
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = {MainActivityModule.class})
    @ActivityScope
    abstract MainActivity contributeMainActivity();

    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = {DummyModule.class})
    @ActivityScope
    abstract DummyActivity contributeDummyActivity();

    //...
}
```

same for services

```
@Module
abstract class ServiceBuilderModule {
    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract MyService contributeAuthenticatorService();

    //...
}
```

Finally here how your `MyApp` should look like

```
public class MyApp extends DaggerApplication() {
    private ApplicationComponent appComponent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        appComponent = DaggerApplicationComponent.builder()
                                                  .application(this)
                                                  .build();
    }

    AndroidInjector<? extends DaggerApplication> applicationInjector(){
        return appComponent;
    }
}
```

Your service should now be injectable, to wrap this up you'll certainly want to inject fragments as well so for example for `MainActivity` fragments you'll make a `FragmentBuilderModule` from your `MainActivityModule`

```
@Module(includes = {FragmentBuilderModule.class})
abstract class MainActivityModule {
    @Binds
    @ActivityScope
    abstract AppCompatActivity bindActivity(MainActivity activity);

    //...
}
```

and here the `FragmentBuilderModule` class

```
@Module
abstract class FragmentBuilderModule {
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = {HomeFragmentModule.class})
    @FragmentScope
    abstract HomeFragment contributeHomeFragment();

    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = DummyFragmentModule.class})
    @FragmentScope
    abstract DummyFragment contributeDummyFragment() ;

    //...
}
```

You can see more from my project template [here](https://github.com/SamYStudiO/beaver) though it's kotlin.

Comment: Thank you very much, this sounds very interessting, but is there a way without switching to AndroidInjector?

Comment: you may add `MyApp.component().inject(this)` from your Service `onCreate` method and add a `void inject(MyService service)` line in your `AppComponent` but Android injector is the right way to go.